# How to increment the index in the existing string?

Tags: shell

I have a following string value and I want to increment index in the string  as below.

```
{
      "name": "poc_param_model_001",
      "type": "DOUBLE",
      "role": "MEASURE",
      "seq": 1
}
```

Here is what I want to do.

```
{
          "name": "poc_param_model_002",
          "type": "DOUBLE",
          "role": "MEASURE",
          "seq": 2
}



{
              "name": "poc_param_model_003",
              "type": "DOUBLE",
              "role": "MEASURE",
              "seq": 3
}

{
              "name": "poc_param_model_004",
              "type": "DOUBLE",
              "role": "MEASURE",
              "seq": 4
}



....

{
              "name": "poc_param_model_099",
              "type": "DOUBLE",
              "role": "MEASURE",
              "seq": 99
 }
```

How to achieve this scenario?

Comment: What you show looks like Json notation and it's not the kind of variables that are handled by conventional shell scripting (bash ore else). Or what are the "string values"?

Comment: This is Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. Maybe you should post it somewhere else, once you will know in which programming language you want to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored in data.txt you can use the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
 if grep -q "^ *\"seq\" *: *[^ ]\+ *\$" <<< "$line"; then
  prefix=$(sed -E "s/^( *\"seq\" *: *)[^ ]+ *\$/\1/" <<< "$line" )
  number=$(sed -E "s/^ *\"seq\" *: *([^ ]+) *\$/\1/" <<< "$line" )
  suffix=$(sed -E "s/^ *\"seq\" *: *[^ ]+( *)\$/\1/" <<< "$line" )
  echo "$prefix$((++number))$suffix"
 else
  echo "$line"
 fi
done < data.txt
```

This script reads all data, finds "seq": and increments the number after it